# QTreeView selectionChanged trigger method

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

I started using a QTreeView Widget for representing my entities of a a database. I want to react to the event of a new entity selection in the treeview, so I can update the state of other widget so they correspond to the current selection of the treeview.
The documentations shows two options for that. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionChanged and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#currentChanged
, but I cannot connect to them the traditional

```
self.treeView_shot.selectionChanged.connect(self.update_RenderView)
```

way I know from working with the widget based approach. I am guessing it doesn't work because selection / currentChanged are not signals but something the documentation refers to as `[virtual protected slot]`. How would you connect the selection change to my update_RenderView method and pass the selected item to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to retrieve the view's [`selectionModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) and then connect to *its* [`selectionChanged`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) signal. Something like this should work:

`self.treeView_shot.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.YOURSLOT)`

Your slot will receive two [`QItemSelection`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselection.html) parameters:

```
def YOURSLOT (selected, deselected):
```

- `selected` is a collection of `QModelIndex`es; these are the items **selected** during the event.
- `deselected` is a collection of `QModelIndex`es; these are the items **deselected** during the event.

Alternatively, you can always query the QTreeView's [`selectedIndexes`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectedIndexes-prop) property to get a list of **all currently selected** items.

Comment: Cool this works, but how do pass the selected item as a parameter?